# Permission issues when accessing /data/data/<packages> folder on Pixel 6a virtual device in Android Studio

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I am currently working with a Pixel 6a virtual device running Android 9 OS in Android Studio (version 2022.3.1). My goal is to access the /data/data/ folder for various packages on the device.

However, when attempting to access this folder, I encounter the following error message: "run-as :package not debuggable." I have also tried using adb, but the results are as follows:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Testing\CLITools\ADB> .\adb.exe shell
generic_x86_arm:/ $ ls
ls: ./init.environ.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.zygote32.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.usb.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init: Permission denied
ls: ./init.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./ueventd.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./init.usb.configfs.rc: Permission denied
ls: ./metadata: Permission denied
acct bugreports charger d    default.prop etc        mnt oem  product sdcard  sys    vendor
bin  cache      config  data dev          lost+found odm proc sbin    storage system
1|generic_x86_arm:/ $
```

I have ensured that the device is running in debug mode, but the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this permission problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `/data/data` is only accessible on rooted devices. Virtual device images included in Android Studio are never rooted.